# Problemas com 2 versões diferentes da biblioteca v7

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, app-compat-v7

Meu app ta apresentando o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

como se eu tivesse usando duas versões da biblioteca de compatibilidade, a 25 e a 27, porem eu já revirei o projeto inteiro e não acho onde estaria declarado a biblioteca 25 pra eu alterar, alguem pode me ajudar

**detalhe:**

estou usando:

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
targetSdkVersion 27
```

Obrigada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### O erro

Esses conflitos acontecem quando uma biblioteca utiliza a mesma dependência, porém, com versões diferentes.

No `gradle` você pode escolher se quer utilizar a dependência por completo ou utilizar apenas parte dela.

No seu caso você está utilizando a versão `27.0.2`, porém outra dependência está utilizando a versão `25.2.0` da `com.android.support:appcompat-v7` e por isso o erro.

#### Correção

Para corrigir esse erro, basta utilizar a dependência `*****` sem a dependência do `appcompat-v7`.

**1.** Identifique qual dependência está causando o erro. Como você tem poucas basta remover até o erro desaparecer.

*(como não dá para ver as outras dependências, não tem como eu informar qual delas está causando conflito)*

**2.** Após identificar a dependência que está causando conflito, basta utilizar o exemplo abaixo:

```
compile('dependência-que-está-causando-conflito') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}
```

> Para mais informações sobre gerenciamento de dependência no Gradle, segue [documentação](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html).

Comment: Resposta certa, e isso serve para as recyclerview e as Support-V4 também :D parabéns Valdeir

Comment: Obrigada. Sua resposta resolveu esse problema, mas estou tendo problemas com o bendito do dex, se vc puder dar uma olhada, eu agradeceria mto. postei aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273770/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease