# Error:Execution failed for task - ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease

Tags: android

Estou recebendo esse erro cada vez que tento dar um `rebuild project`

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
> >     java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with
> >     arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --output
> >     C:\Users\M\Documents\MY_APP_NAME\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\release\folders\1000\1f\main
> >     C:\Users\M\Documents\MY_APP_NAME\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar}

Quem souber o que eu preciso fazer POR FAVOR me ajude, pq não consigo atualizar meu app >:[, ele até compila, porém os dispositivos não deixa instalar...

Meu build.gradle é esse:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MY_PACKAGE"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 8
        versionName "5.2"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
}
```

**OBS** - isso ocorre na versão debug tb. Já to surtando!!! Alguem sabe o que fazer...

Obrigada.

**EDITADO**

Agora ta aparecendo isso qd chega nessa tarefa:

> :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug

(ultima tarefa q aparece no Gradle Console)

e no Messages aparece:

> Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources,
>   :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
>   Error:Failed to complete Gradle execution.
>
> Cause: Foi forçado o cancelamento de uma conexão existente pelo host
>   remoto

Tentei atualizar meu gralde.build para as ultimas versões das ferramentas, mas nada tb.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MY_PACKAGE"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 8
        versionName "5.2"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile project(':adcolony-sdk-3.1.2')
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' //for Inmobi
}
```

add no Android Manifets  a tag do multiDex, mas nada tb.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
```

Engraçado q meu app já esta publicado (to tentando atualizar só), isso só começou a acontecer nessa nova versão do Android Studio (3.0.1), q alias acaba com a RAM do PC!!! Tentei desinstalar essa versão e instalar a antiga, mas dai aparece erro tb.

Alguem sabe como resolver o problema? Obrigada.

Answer (score 1):

#### Sobre o erro

Provavelmente seu app está com mais de *64K* métodos/referências.

Arquivos de aplicativo Android contêm arquivos de `bytecode` executáveis no formato de arquivos `Dalvik Executable` (ou simplesmente `DEX`).

A especificação do formato `DEX` limita o total de métodos que podem ser referenciados em um só arquivo `DEX` a 65.536 — isso inclui seu projeto e as dependências dele.

No contexto da ciência da computação, o termo Kilo, K, denota 1.024 (ou 2^10). Como 65.536 equivale a 64 X 1.024, esse limite é chamado de “limite de 64 K referências”.

#### Solução

Para corrigir você precisa seguir dois passos:

**1.** Adicionar a dependência `multidex`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

**2.** Ativar o `multidex` em sua configuração:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "MY_PACKAGE"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 8
    versionName "5.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

**3.** Você também pode modificar a sua classe `Application`, basta estender a classe `MultiDexApplication`.

Caso você não possua uma classe `Application`, basta adicionar o código abaixo no nó `<application>`, em seu `manifest.xml`

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
```

Caso você já possua a classe `Application`, basta estender. Ex:

```
public class CustomApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    /* Código aqui */
}
```

Comment: Oi, obrigada pela sua ajuda! Só pra eu entender direito, esse dex se refere ao tamanho final do app, ou a qtd de metodos de um arq especifico, pq meu app tem 70M de tamanho, já foi publicado, e sp compilou normalmente com as versões anteriores o AS, nessa nova versão 3.0.1 q apareceu essa marmota!!! Eu editei minha pergunta, se você puder dar uma olhada, eu agradeço mto.

Comment: @EmilyR Isso não é devido ao tamanho do app e sim a quantidade de métodos de classes/referência que o projeto utiliza. Editei o item 2 da minha resposta.